# Checking contents of Uploaded file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am using ASP.NEt MVC . I want to upload .zip files for which I am using html input file upload control on my view. 
I want only .zip files to be uploaded. 
I want to check that my .zip contains only two files - both having extensions .txt and one of them having name "start".
Can anyone please suggest me about how to check this? How can we assure that the uploaded .zip is really a zipped folder and not any other file having just .zip extension.
can we use HttpPostedFileBase.ContentType?

thanks in advance,
kaps

Answer (score 0):

The `ContentType` is simply filled in by the client browser, so you can't really trust it. The only way is to try & parse the file on the server: use something like [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) to open the .zip file and confirm that it has two files in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to determine whether file is a zip file or not. And you can do much more with dotnetzip.

You can verify like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormItems item, HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
            //check for zip file
            try
            {
                ZipFile.CheckZip(files.FileName); //just pass the name of the file
            }
            catch
            {
                //not a zip file
            }
            
}
```

OR

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormItems item, HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
            //check for zip file
            try
            {
                ZipFile.Read(files.InputStream); //read the zip contents by passing the input stream
            }
            catch
            {
                //not a zip file
            }
            
}
```

Make sure that you include namespace `using Ionic.Zip;` and add a reference to that dll as well.

Hope this helps